# Extract a word from a sentence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, match

I have the following string:

```
str = "XXX host:1233455 YYY ZZZ!"
```

I want to extract the value after `host:` from this string.

Is there any optimal way in Ruby to do this using RegExp, avoiding multiple loops?
Any solution is welcome.

Comment: Some of the ways I saw is iterating through each word in the line and then comparing for string match.

Comment: `host:\K.*` or `(?<=host:).*` , pls do search before posting.

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks..but your solution didn't help me.

Comment: I thought you want all the chars next to `host`. But this is asked here n number of times. So always try to post your attempts at very first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have numbers, use the following regex:

```
(?<=host:)\d+
```

The lookbehind will find the numbers right after `host:`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vba6SM):

```
str = "XXX host:1233455 YYY ZZZ!"
puts str.match(/(?<=host:)\d+/)
```

Note that if you want to match alphanumerics and not any punctuation, you can replace `\d+` with `\w+`.

Also, if you also have dots, or commas inside, you can use

```
/(?<=host:)\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*/
```

It will extract values like `4,445` or `44.45.455`.

**UPDATE**:

In case you need a more universal solution (especially if you need to use the regex on another platform where look-behind is not supported (as in JavaScript), use capture group approach:

```
str.match(/\bhost:(\d+)/).captures.first
```

Note that `\b` makes sure we find `host:` as a whole word, not `localhost:`. `(\d+)` is the capture group whose value we can refer to with the backreferences, or via `.captures.first` in Ruby.

Comment: @Raj: Avinash Raj's suggestion was wrong because it had `.*` that matched any 1 or more characters. Please check mine. If you have doubts, please drop a comment.

Comment: \@stribizhev: What's the advantage of using a look-behind here?

Comment: This way you get a "cleaner" match and you do not have to meddle with capturing groups. IMHO, in Ruby, it is convenient. On the other hand, you can also use `str.match(/\bhost:(\d+)/).captures.first`. Note I have added `\b` - a word boundary - to match `host`, not, say, `localhost`.

Comment: I get the point. So, it's mainly to avoid the runtime overhead from having a (single) capturing group? Because from the viewpoint of readability, I would regard `\bhost:(\d+)` cleaner.

Comment: @user1934428: Capturing groups are universal across regex, so if you plan to use the same regex on different platforms, use that one. If you want the simplicity of accessing the value itself, use a look-around based solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
str[/host:(\d+)/, 1]
# => "1233455"
```

Answer (score 2):

What about the regex:

```
host:(\S+)
```

Here you can find a [demo](http://rubular.com/r/eLwTXSszjb).

Comment: Just FYI: The use of `\S+` might result in an unwanted trailing punctuation at the end of the captured text.

Comment: @stribizhev: thanks for your note. Actually the OP did not really stated a validation for the value, we can just guess that it should be a number, but could it also be a floating point one? It's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the value for example.

```
str.match(/host:(\d+)/).captures.first
```